# addEventListener not being added in conditional _.each for option

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to each option in a select tag. The event listener is only being added if the queryselector finds options. Everything is working until I try to add to eventListener.

I am able to see that the _.each loop is looping over each option so I know I am accessing the  tag. The commented out code is what I've used to make sure the other parts are working. I'm not even getting an error that the event is unable to be added.

```
<SELECT>
<OPTION class="renewal_action">convert</OPTION>
<OPTION class="renewal_action">expire</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

```
let renew_action_select = row_node.querySelectorAll('.renewal_action')
    console.log(renew_action_select)
    if(renew_action_select.length){
        _.each(renew_action_select, function(renew_action){
            console.log(renew_action)
            renew_action.addEventListener('click', function()
                {
                    console.log('in renew')

                })
            }
        )
    }
```

I'm expecting to get a message in the console when I click on one of the options to confirm that the event has been added but nothing is happening. There is no error message to let me know the event has not been added.

Comment: can you show your markup?

Comment: I've added the html

Comment: why are you attaching the event listener on the option element?, if you want to get the selected item, set a change event listener on the select element

Answer (score 2):

```js
const select = document.querySelector('select');

select.addEventListener('change', function () {
  console.log(select.value);
})
```

```html
<select>
  <option>convert</option>
  <option>expire</option>
</select>
```

Comment: From what i've read, it's better to chose the options and not the select.

Comment: ok, then you probably need a set of checkbox or radio buttons

Comment: Targeting the select works for what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Its better to have the event on the select, not the options.